Help in understanding ERC721.onERC721Received()
I'm curious to understand on how things work. I'm playing this CTF where the two things must happen:
-- the 'to' address provided must have code.length = 0 (we can bypass this by calling the function in the constructor)
-- the same 'to' address should also implement the onERC721Received() and should return IERC721TokenReceiver.onERC721Received.selector
I'm confused about how to achieve this. Even though I write onERC721Received () in the Contract, an external contract couldn't call this as it would be in the run-time code. I cannot call onERC721Received() in the constructor as I cannot call external functions inside the constructor.

Maybe you're meant to call a precompile?

Hahaha Yeah, that's the solution.

Have you tried running the mentioned solution?
When you call the target contract from the constructor, the code length will be zero, and the target contract will call onERC721Received()  which should execute without any problem. The onERC721Received()  is not supposed to be called by you.
Something like this?
"@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721Receiver.sol";

contract CTFChallenge is IERC721Receiver {
    constructor(address targetContract, bytes memory data) {
        // Call the target function in the constructor
        (bool success, ) = targetContract.call(data);
        require(success, "Target call failed");
    }

    // Implement onERC721Received
    function onERC721Received(
        address operator,
        address from,
        uint256 tokenId,
        bytes calldata data
    ) external pure override returns (bytes4) {
        // Return the correct selector
        return IERC721Receiver.onERC721Received.selector;
    }
}


The thing is, as the CTFChallenge is calling the external contract(targetContract) in constructor -- creation code, the runtime code isn't been deployed yet. So even though when targetContract makes a call back to CTFChallenge onERC721Received(), it won't execute nor return anything.
Anyways, I've solved the CTF challenge. Thanks for your message mate

Cool, please add the CTF question and post the answer as well, it might help the community.

Could definetely post the CTF link here but as per the rules, I shouldn't disclose the  solution anywhere.
Here's the CTF link: https://onlypwner.xyz/challenges/16
One of the best ways to learn more about EVM in depth.

No worries. Thanks.
